# How to filter the text under the strong tag?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i have this code:

```
url = 'http://www.topsoftzone.com/program/12721/Windows_Phone_7.html'
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup
print soup.find('table',{'class':'download_tab'}).find('td',{'width':'55%'}).find('strong').text
```

I should get output like this: 09/29/2011 (Submitted: 09/08/2011)

but the code output: Updated:

Comment: I edited it but still can't get the output

Comment: Look at the HTML again. That text isn't in a `<strong>` tag.

Comment: It is under the <strong> but I dont know how to filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're missing the table row there `tr` between `table`and `td`

in any case, consider using lxml with xpath instead

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(url, etree.HTMLParser())
l = tree.xpath('//table[@class="download_tab"]/tr/td[@width="55%"]/text()')
print l[1]

09/29/2011 (Submitted: 09/08/2011)
```

EDIT: without lxml as requested

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
l = soup.find('table',{'class':'download_tab'}).find('tr').find('td',{'width':'55%'}).findAll(text=True)
print l[2]

09/29/2011 (Submitted: 09/08/2011)
```

Comment: I just need 09/29/2011 (Submitted: 09/08/2011) as the output.

Comment: Thanks, its working. But is there anyway that if dont want to use lxml?

Answer (score 1):

You need more error checking, but this works

```
import lxml.html
import urllib
import sys

link = "http://www.topsoftzone.com/program/12721/Windows_Phone_7.html"

page = urllib.urlopen(link).read()

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page)
doc.make_links_absolute(link)

found_text = doc.xpath(u".//table[@class='download_tab']/tr/td[@width='55%']/text()")
try:
    print found_text[1].strip()
except:
    print "Not found"
```

Comment: Thanks @Deck, it works but how to do it without lxml?